# Select ALL within a GET parameter

Tags: json, get, postman

I have the following GET call:

```
https://*[databoardname].com*/api/*[companyname]*/databoards/10062?1=106&10=2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z&11=2019-04-30T00:00:00.000Z
```

This works fine at pulling back the data relating to company '106' as defined in parameter 1.

However I would like to be able to pull all companies data back in one GET call.

I have tried calling it like `"1":"106,107"` etc but cannot seem to get it to work?

Can anyone advise the best way to write this call so i can pull back data for all available companies (company id's 106-116) or just 'Select ALL' on parameter 1?

I am using postman to make the call.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Unless the API you're posting against explicitly supports that type of querying then what you're trying to do is not possible. On the postman side I can think of at least 2 options:

1. Create a single request, which you already have, then copy it 10 times changing only company id. All these requests should be in the same folder so that you can later run them as a collection.
2. The better alternative is to create a data file with all the company ids then run then run the collection and postman will take care of iterating through all the companies and you only need a single request. For instance your data file may look like this:

> ```
> company
> 106
> 107
> ...
> ...
> 116
> ```

Then your request would simply look something like this:

```
https://*[databoardname].com*/api/{{company}}/databoards/10062?1=106&10=2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z&11=2019-04-30T00:00:00.000Z
```

Note that for company you'll be using a Postman variable with the syntax `{{company}}`

Here's more information regarding Postman data files:

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/working_with_data_files/